# Executar classe expecífica ao iniciar aplicação web

Tags: java, java-ee, scheduler

Tenho um classe que necessitaria ser executada junto com a aplicação web, toda a vez que ela iniciasse. Eu subiria a aplicação para o servidor e essa classe necessitaria ser executada.

Essa aplicação esta rodando no Wildfly, e tambem esta usando Spring Framework.

Nessa clase roda um Job, nada mais que programar uma `Scheduler` para ser executada numa hora fixa do dia. Se houver outra forma de iniciar (talvez, mais correta) esse agendamento de processo, certamente me ajudaria tambem. 
Parace uma pergunta simples, mas juro que não encontrei uma resolução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei dizer se tem uma mais correta porque não conheço sua infra, mas eu criaria um serviço com Jenkins para executar na hora programada.
Outra alternativa, como você já projetou, é colocar isso em uma classe de start da aplicação mas preciso saber qual o framework ou tipo de projeto que está utilizando.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada no Jenkins, ver o que consigo, obrigado. Eu editei a pergunta, para colocar os dados que você comentou, esta rodando com o Spring Framework. Essa classe de start que você comentou, como configuro?

Comment: Verifique qual das duas formas você está fazendo... 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Se for baseado em código, onde vc tem uma classe responsável por esse "start", você pode implementar lá.

Comment: Consegui amigo, obrigado. Esse link que você compartilhou me ajudou um pouco, acabei que vi um exemplo onde ele iniciava no web.xml um "listener" e direcionava uma classe para ele.